# can you use kubectl patch to add a value dynamically

Tags: kubernetes, patch, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

I am to patch an image onto init containers

my image is stored in a variable called $IMAGE_NAME

When I run

> kubectl patch deployment production-art-backend -p  {"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"initContainers":[{"name":"run-migrations","image":"$IMAGE_NAME"}]}}}}

it patches the image as 'IMAGE_NAME' and not the value inside the variable IMAGE_NAME, how can I patch the image dynamically?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a bash issue, not necessarily a `kubectl` issue!

Because the JSON string requires double quotes, you need to wrap the variable inside single quotes. Try this:

```
kubectl patch deployment production-art-backend -p {"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"initContainers":[{"name":"run-migrations","image":"'${IMAGE_NAME}'"}]}}}}
```

Comment: I was naively adding spaces or even + haha. We need js/python style shells

Answer (score 3):

Please try below command :

```
kubectl patch deployment production-art-backend --patch="{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"initContainers\":[{\"name\":\"run-migrations\",\"image\":\"$IMAGE_NAME\"}]}}}}"
```

It worked for me.