# patch from variable in script not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Why is this not working from script?

```
kubectl patch configmap/config-domain \
 --namespace knative-serving \
 --type merge \
 --patch "{"data":{"${DOMAIN_NAME}":""}}"
```

This expands into this:

```
kubectl patch configmap/config-domain \
 --namespace knative-serving \
 --type merge \
 --patch "{"data":{"MyDomain.com":""}}"
```

But nothing gets patched/merged?

If I manually do this then it works with using " ' ". Note: `'{"data":{"MyDomain.com":""}}'`:

```
kubectl patch configmap/config-domain \
 --namespace knative-serving \
 --type merge \
 --patch '{"data":{"MyDomain.com":""}}'
```

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51690446/7695859

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can you use kubectl patch to add a value dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689777/can-you-use-kubectl-patch-to-add-a-value-dynamically)